# NDWI from Landsat 8

Tags: remote-sensing

I have layer stacked Landsat 8 image, how can I calculate [Normalized difference water index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_water_index) (NDWI) from it?

I would have been able to calculate it easily using the raster calculator, if I had the green and NIR bands individually.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might not be explaining clearly enough the exact nature of the "stacked Landsat 8 image" that you do have. Landsat 8 does have both green and near infrared channels ([bands 3 and 5 respectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_8#Sensors)); what channels are present in your image(s)?

Comment: the stacked landsat 8 image has bands 1-5 in it. How can the raster calculator use bands 3 and 5 from the stacked image to calculate NDWI? I can do it easily as i mentioned earlier if I had the individual bands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is your question something like "I have bands 1 and 5 and I want to do a calculation that requires bands 3 and 5, how can I do it?" Is it possible that "you can't" might be the answer? I think that the more details you edit back into the original question (not just in comments) the more likely others can help. I'm no expert on this topic.

Comment: Please indicate which software you are using.

Comment: Something is lost in translation here. Does your file have bands 1 *through* 5 or 1 *and* 5.

Comment: I am using arcgis 10.5.1 and the image (landsat 8) has bands 1,2,3,4,5 stacked.